# swiper slider showing single bullet with jquery tabs?

Tags: jquery, tabs, swiper.js

```
<div class="panel" style="background : transparent; border: none;">
        <div id="tabs-centre"  style="background : transparent;margin-left:5px;border: none;">
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-centre-1">op</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-centre-2">oop</a></li>
        </ul>


        <div id="tabs-centre-1">
        <!-- Swiper -->
        <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">

        <div class="swiper-slide roundbox">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide roundbox">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide roundbox">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide roundbox">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide roundbox">
        </div>


        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination" ></div>
         <!-- Add Arrows -->
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        </div><!--Swiper Ends-->
        </div><!-- End: Tabs1 -->

        <div id="tabs-centre-2">
        <!-- Swiper -->
        <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">

        <div class="swiper-slide roundbox">
        </div>


        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination" ></div>
         <!-- Add Arrows -->
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        </div><!--Swiper Ends-->
        </div><!-- End: Tabs2 -->

        </div>
        </div>
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    slidesPerView: 3,
    centeredSlides: false,
    paginationClickable: true,
    autoplay: 2500,
    spaceBetween: 15,
});
```

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rzeiwald/bj3z4L74). I am trying to use `idangero` swiper with jQuery tabs but I'm getting all the results I want except `pagination.slider` pagination showing only one bullet if second tab is having single `slide`. It works fine when used with single tab but I don't know how to apply swiper when two or more tabs are required. How can I do this?

Comment: your missing the `<script>`  tag around your JavaScript code

Comment: I am sorry but i have not given proper code i know that we should write <script> tag.. see the fiddle link i have given

Answer (score 0):

You have to differentiate between the two sliders.  Make the first one be something like `class="swiper-container slide-on-tab-a"` and the second one be `class="swiper-container slide-on-tab-b"`.  Then, when you initialize them in javascript ...

`new Swiper('.swiper-container.slide-on-tab-a', {
  pagination: '.swiper-container.slide-on-tab-a .swiper-pagination',
  nextButton: '.swiper-container.slide-on-tab-a .swiper-button-next',
  prevButton: '.swiper-container.slide-on-tab-a .swiper-button-prev',`

and separately,

`new Swiper('.swiper-container.slide-on-tab-b', {
  pagination: '.swiper-container.slide-on-tab-b .swiper-pagination',
  nextButton: '.swiper-container.slide-on-tab-b .swiper-button-next',
  prevButton: '.swiper-container.slide-on-tab-b .swiper-button-prev',`

And you'll want to read up on *css selectors* if you don't understand that syntax.